# What is the default location of Winston logs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, logging, logfiles, winston

I am using something like this:

```
var winston = require('winston'), logger = new (winston.Logger)({
  transports: [
    new (winston.transports.Console) (),
    new (winston.transports.File) ({filename: 'test.log'})
  ]
});

logger.log('Hello world');
```

I cannot find the log file `test.log` anywhere on my system and no exception or info in the console either.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Nevermind, I found the answer. If you do not specify directory, it is in the same directory as the code.

Comment: or rather root of the project.

Answer (score 1):

Paste the following snippet in your `winston.helper.js`

```
// create directory for logs first
if (!fs.existsSync("logs")) {
    fs.mkdirSync("logs");
}
```

*OR*

You can write a command in your `package.json` script For e.g.

```
"dev": "mkdir logs | ..."
```

Answer (score 0):

set the route of the file name like this '${__dirname}/filename' if this not working change the colon into back quote